# JavaScript. Передача значений переменных из одного файла проекта в другой

Tags: javascript

коллеги. Попалась мне задача на работе - добавить кнопку на странице для отображения всех записей. В JS пока не разбираюсь, делаю по образцу кнопки, которая отображает следующие 20 записей.
У меня есть два файла в проекте: в первом файле идет получение текущего состояния страницы, во втором файле описывается действия по клику. Мне необходимо перенести значения переменных из первого файла js во второй js чтобы расcчитать необходимое количество записей для отображения. Как это можно сделать в JS? Буду очень Вам благодарен.

первый файл:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
//все эти переменные инициализируются другой функцией в файле. Их необходимо передать
var requestsSize = 0,
    totalRequestsSize = 0,
    requestsTake = 0,
    lastRequestSize = 0;
//дальше следует остальной код .....
})();
```

второй файл:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var take = 20, //значения количества записей, которое необходимо отобразить. Используется другой кнопкой, которую я взял в качества образца.
    page = 0; 

    $('.j-full_requests').click(function () {
        page++;

        requestsFilterQuery = $.extend({}, form.serializeObject(), {
            take: take, // необходимо сюда поместить необходимое количество для полного отображения
            skip: (page * take),
            newSearch: false,
            sortParameter: $('.j-requests_sort').val(),
            sortDirection: $('.j-request_mode').val()
        });
        //дальше следует остальной код ....
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

первый файл:

```
(function(global) {
'use strict';
  //все эти переменные инициализируются другой функцией в файле. Их необходимо передать
  var requestInfo = {
    requestsSize: 0,
    totalRequestsSize: 0,
    requestsTake: 0,
    lastRequestSize: 0
  };
  global.requestInfo = requestInfo;
  //дальше следует остальной код .....
})(window);
```

второй файл:

```
(function(global) {
'use strict';

  // ...    

  $('.j-full_requests').click(function () {
    var requestInfo = global.requestInfo; // use properties of requestInfo below
    // ...
    //дальше следует остальной код ....
    });
})(window);
```

Comment: Обьясните, что window - это глобальная глобальная область видимости, все дела.... Новичок может не понять как это работает и просто скопирует то что работает. Не надо так)